# How to control the size of the plot inside the figure in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Please see attached graph. There are only two items on the x-axis, yet it takes the whole space. I like to leave some blank on each side so that the actual graph only fills 25% to 75% of x axis.  I am not exactly sure keyword in matplotlib controls that.

To be clear, I want **Last Year** around 25% of x axis and  **This Year** around 75% of x axis. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? What you are looking for is the `ax.set_xlim()` method.

Comment: `plt.margins(x=0.5)` seems more general as you don't need to calculate the exact xlims.